# Receive real-time notifications in a web application from an AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, socket.io, push-notification, web-push

I need to implement a real-time notification functionality in a web application from an AWS lambda function. How to achieve this functionality? We have an AWS lambda function that gets triggered on an SNS event. I need to show this SNS event details in the web app through a real-time API in Node JS and send it to the web application.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What details do you need to show?

Comment: You can use the W3C Push API / Web Push.

Answer (score 0):

> ... AWS AppSync can push real-time data updates over Websockets to millions of clients.

[AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/appsync/) may help, check this aws service please.